# How To Specify Two Default Dates In Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using the following expression to pull a default date from yesterday:

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,Today())
```

The business requirements changed and now they want to see yesterday AND today. Is it possible to add onto this expression to include yesterday and today?

Comment: Why not give yourself some flexibility and create separate parameters for start and end dates that default to yesterday and today, respectively?  Your filter criteria will most likely be a bit cleaner for it.

Comment: Is your date parameter setup to allow multiple values?  One way to tell if it is would be that it appear as a drop-down instead of a calendar in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the parameter to yesterday date and change this in your query.

```
WHERE [DateColumn] >= @DataParam
```

If you want to show the dates the report is using, try this in a textbox:

```
="Dates: " & Parameters!DateParam.Value & "-" Today()
```

**UPDATE:** If your parameter is multivalued you have to add two default values using these expression:

```
=Today()
```

```
=Today.AddDays(-1)
```

Then in your query change this:

```
WHERE [DateColumn] IN (@DateParam)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Esh, I should have done that. I'll make that change to the query and give it a test (though it should work). Thanks mate!